# Python app created via Pyinstaller does not run

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made a simple, one-file script that I would like to share with the end-user. I found that Pyinstaller does the job so I refactor my project structure regarding.

I have a project dir. Inside that, I have the package that has an empty `__init__.py` and a `__main__.py` with the actual script with a few include to libraries like opencv-python, numpy, etc. Outside of the project, I have a setup.py and an entry-point script that imports the main function from the `__main__.py` and calls it.

Then I have created the executable against this entry-point with PyInstaller in --onefile mode. When I use the created executable on my machine it does the job perfectly but when I send it to the end-user it ends up with an error (see below). I am not quite sure whats this error means but I saw paths in that to my dev environment which should be not there on other machines. It looks like it missing the dependencies but I thought that PyInstaller bundles these dependencies into the executable.

What am I missing here? I have read many regarding questions here in StackOverflow but I couldn't find a solution.

I developed this script using PyCharm on the latest macOS within a venv created by PyCharm. The venv folder is in the project dir - I don't know that could be a problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Users/hordon/Documents/DEV/projects/scan_detect/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "/Users/hordon/Documents/DEV/projects/scan_detect/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "platform.py", line 116, in <module>
  File "/Users/hordon/Documents/DEV/projects/scan_detect/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "subprocess.py", line 153, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/wk/cwx1b16j50z5_yt1ynq82hr00000gn/T/_MEI7eUUkV/select.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /var/folders/wk/cwx1b16j50z5_yt1ynq82hr00000gn/T/_MEI7eUUkV/select.cpython-37m-darwin.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /var/folders/wk/cwx1b16j50z5_yt1ynq82hr00000gn/T/_MEI7eUUkV/select.cpython-37m-darwin.so
[15314] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

Comment: Is the end user on the same OS as you?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem ，and sadly it's a problem of mac os. So, if you want to support different version of mac os, you need to build your app on the oldest version of mac os.

"In Mac OS X, components from one version of the OS are usually compatible with later versions, but they may not work with earlier versions.

The only way to be certain your app supports an older version of Mac OS X is to run PyInstaller in the oldest version of the OS you need to support."

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#making-mac-os-x-apps-forward-compatible